# Is it possible to have a live m3u8 stream play in phonegap applications?

Tags: cordova, ffmpeg, m3u8

I've built a Drupal back-end website for streaming live m3u8 streams, and when I play these streams over to an Android Java application it works, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in phonegap as well.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "m3u8 stream".  Those files are just playlists.  Are you referring to HLS?  HTTP progressive streaming?  SHOUTcast/Icecast style streams?

Comment: you know what he meant...and yes you may have to write a plug in for it to be cross platform...dealing with this issue now. Works on some androids not al firmwares and does not work on ios at all.

Comment: On iOS just redirect to the m3u8.